# Allow My(!) sites to communicate with Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have ownership on `A.com` ( *I wish...*)

I also own `B.com`

is there any HTML *tag  / Token / code* that can Allow `B.com` to do : `top.myFunc()`

```
 ________________
| A.com          |
|   __________   |
|   | B.com   |  |
|   |_________|  |
|________________|
```

*p.s. : I've seen many question about this topic but none regarding a person owns 2 domains and **want**  to allow this.*

Comment: The browser does not care who owns the domain. I think you'll need to have some sort of API that both can interact with to allow communication.

Comment: @sachleen I know . but I think I've heard that if you put a special tag or line of code , it _CAN_ recognize and access.....

Comment: I don't know the answer but I have seen files called "crossdomain.xml" on many servers which has lists of sites that they wanted to allow cross communication with. Maybe the answer lies there or maybe that's just for server side access not js.

Comment: The [same domain origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will generally block requests from B.com to A.com though there are ways to break this from A.com to B.com.

Comment: I have never heard of anything like that (doesn't mean it doesn't exist) and it doesn't make any sense. It would require the browser to do a whois lookup on the domains to verify they belong to the same person and then allow cross site scripts? That's new to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These articles may help you

http://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe
http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the perfect answer to that question, but I would like to point out, that Facebook Apps do something like that!

Facebook Apps reside in B.com, while Facebook itself is A.com.
To access SOME of the methods Facebook offers in their API, you have to include the all.js inside of you B.com/index.html which is then loaded from A.com/all.js.
This way, you're at least able to call action offered by this all.js File.

Facebook also uses the channel.html file to make cross domain access possible.

Comment: Look into the Channel File section of this Facebook documentation to learn more about that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Does anything stop you from using [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) ?